# MariaDB: SQL to remove duplicates between different timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mariadb

I have the following table and want to remove duplicates between the oldest and newest timestamp.

| timestamp | type | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-10-01 04:51:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 04:54:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 04:56:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 05:01:42 | mod | on |
| 2019-10-01 05:21:42 | mod | on |
| 2019-10-01 05:30:42 | mod | on |
| 2019-10-01 05:43:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 05:51:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 06:02:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 06:05:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 06:10:42 | mod | on |
| 2019-10-01 06:15:42 | mod | on |
| 2019-10-01 06:25:42 | mod | on |

This is the result what I want with a generic SQL statement. I need the first timestamp if status is changed.

| timestamp | type | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-10-01 04:51:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 05:01:42 | mod | on |
| 2019-10-01 05:43:42 | mod | off |
| 2019-10-01 06:10:42 | mod | on |

Thanks for help :-)

Comment: What did you try to solve this yourself? (SO is not a free code writing service)

Comment: Do you need: (1) select only shown rows, do not alter the source table data (2) delete all another rows from the source table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e57858de46dbb934ea6c1bb51f63c326)

```
SELECT `timestamp`,type,state
FROM (
  SELECT 
    `timestamp`,
    type,
    state,
    LEAD(state) OVER (ORDER BY `timestamp`) as Next,
    LAG(state) OVER (ORDER BY `timestamp`) as Previous
  FROM t1
  ) x
WHERE state=Next AND (state<>Previous OR Previous is null);
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not my expectation to consume a free writing service :-). I can handle low level sql but I have no experience which functions are exists. My short research was not successful or I don't have understand the results for my case. Thanks for your help. Now I will try to understand how lead() and lag() works for similar problems.